# Как загрузить модель предсказания один раз, а не при каждом вызове скрипта?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

У меня есть очень простой API, который предсказывает наличие или отсутствие небезопасного поведения водителя. Помимо определения нерегулярности поведения, API позволяет охарактеризовать совершенное нарушение.

API также позволяет генерировать тепловую карту, чтобы определить, какая часть изображения позволила моделям сделать свои прогнозы.

Пока что API загружает модель ClassificationModel каждый раз, когда мы запрашиваем ее на изображении, переданном через скрипт. Как загрузить модель только один раз?

`main.py`

```
from model import ClassificationModel
import argparse
import os


def predict_img(img_path, with_heatmap=False):
    model = ClassificationModel() <--- Aqui descargo el modelo cada vez que llamo a predict_img

    row = model.predict(img_path=img_path, row=None, img=None, load=True, original_image_path=img_path,
                        print_heatmap=with_heatmap)

    results = row.to_json()
    print(results)

    return results


if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--path", "-p", help="path of the image", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--heatmap", "-heat", help="generate heatmap or not", required=True)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if not(os.path.exists(args.path)):
        raise FileNotFoundError("{} does not exist.".format(args.path))

    elif args.path.split(".")[-1] not in ["png", "jpg", "jpeg"]:
        raise TypeError("The file is not a valid image file.")

    if args.heatmap.upper() == "TRUE":
        args.heatmap = True
    else:
        args.heatmap = False

    result = predict_img(img_path=args.path, with_heatmap=args.heatmap)
```

`model.py`

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(40)
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

import settings as st

from predict import Predict


class ClassificationModel(Predict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_pos = [
            "safe driving",
            "texting - right",
            "talking to the phone - right",
            "texting - left",
            "talking on the phone - left",
            "operating the radio",
            "drinking",
            "reaching behind",
            "hair and makeup",
            "talking to passenger"
        ]

        self.image_size = 384
        self.generator = ImageDataGenerator(brightness_range=[0.7, 1.5],
                                            rotation_range=35,
                                            fill_mode='nearest',
                                            zoom_range=0.125,
                                            rescale=1. / 255)

        self.model = load_model(st.model_path)
        self.threshold = 0.5
        self.n_step = 5
        self.normal_index = 0
```

`settings.py`

```
model_path = "./model/classification.h5"

th = [0.5,
      0.5,
      0.5,
      0.5,
      0.5,
      0.5,
      0.5,
      0.5,
      0.5,
      0.5]
```

Я думал о том, чтобы сделать цикл while с самого начала. Мне посоветовали сделать систему, которая ждет некоторых входных данных через http/sockets но я не знаю, как это сделать.

Comment: [Сохраняйте](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-pickle.html) загруженную модель в файл. И проверяйте каждый раз, есть ли уже сохранённый файл, из которого можно достать модель.

Comment: Это мудро, @КириллМалышев . Спасибо, я попробую реализовать это.

Comment: Я думаю, что это уже решено в настройках, @КириллМалышев . На данный момент я думаю, что единственное, что можно сделать, это развернуть этот сценарий и ждать новых запросов. С этим я могу справиться, выполнив цикл while. Настоящая проблема заключается в том, как управлять запросами. Я думал о системе запросов http/socket, но не знаю, где найти документацию по этому вопросу.